# vue.js Why is my child component updating the parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have a child component that functions as an edit section.  It copies a single prop on `created()` to serve as the v-model for editing, as I don't want any edits to reflect on the parent until the user clicks the save button.  When the user clicks save, I `$emit` the edited model back to the parent to update.  In theory.

In reality, the parent model seems to be reactive whenever I edit the child component, despite the child `<input>` supposedly acting on a copy of the passed prop.  Why is this, and how do I prevent it?

```html
<h2>{{ location.name }}</h2>
<edit-location v-if="editing" :location="location" />
```

EditLocation.vue:

```js
<template>
  <input v-model="copyOfLocation.name">
  <button>Save</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    location: {
      required: false,
      type: Object,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      copyOfLocation: {},
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.copyOfLocation = this.location;
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're assigning the object to a new property but it's still the same object. Despite the name it isn't actually a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While assigning the value of `location` to `copyOfLocation`, it actually assigns the reference. That make the issue.
Try

```
this.copyOfLocation = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(this.location));
```

while copying the value in the `created` hook. This will not copy the reference.

```
this.copyOfLocation = _.cloneDeep(this.location); // cloning using Lodash library.
```

Comment: that did the trick!  wasn't aware of the shallow copy but that makes sense.